# PHP - replace http with https in URL

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am trying to figure out how to add s after HTTP once a user checks a box in the html form.

I have in my PHP,

```
$url = 'http://google.com';

if(!isset($_POST['https'])) { 
  //something here
}
```

So basically, when the user checks a box with the name="https" i want to add s to $url's http making it https://google.com.

I have little knowledge on PHP and if someone can explain to me how to go about doing this, this would be really helpful! thanks.

Answer (score 81):

```
$url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $url);
```

Comment: good solution, but it is better for incase-sensitive: 
`$url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $url);`

Comment: i tested this solution, unfortunatly this was not working, i tried next solution with "str_replace" and get the result.

Comment: str_replace didnt work for me, but the original did. Also many thanks for this great solution, saved a giant issue with a wordpress theme im customizing that would otherwise force mixed content over SSL and break SSL connection.

Answer (score 15):

```
$url = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $url );
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
$url = '%s//google.com';
$protocol = 'http:';

if(!isset($_POST['https'])) { 
    $protocol = 'https:';
}

$url = sprintf($url, $protocol);
```

Comment: thanks for the code but I can't break up the $url because it is being used in a previous function which requires the entire url. Would there be another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

When you consider case-insensitive, then use [str_ireplace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function.

Example:

```
$url = str_ireplace( 'http://', 'https://', $url );
```

Alternatively, incase you ant to replace URL scheme in CDN files.
Example:

```
$url = str_ireplace( 'http:', 'https:', $url );
```

This... *(with `'https:'`)*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Becomes... *(`'https:'` has been replaced)*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know on how many pages you want this to happen onward the user checks the box, but one answer is JavaScript and the [base](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/base.html) tag.

With the `base` tag, you can force a different origin, what your relative URL-s will be resolved against.

I you are using it ina  form, and the user ticks the checkbox them sumbits the form, all other pages will be viewed from the *https* site, so you can use relative URL-s everywhere, just insert a different `base` tag when the user wants to change the site form or to http(s).

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't replace urls which contain other urls, for instance **http://foo.com/redirect-to/http://newfoo.com**

```
$desiredScheme = "http"; // convert to this scheme;
$parsedRedirectUri = parse_url($myCurrentUrl);
if($parsedRedirectUri['scheme'] !== $desiredScheme) {
    $myCurrentUrl= substr_replace($myCurrentUrl, $desiredScheme, 0, strlen( $parsedRedirectUri['scheme'] ));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = 1;
$url = str_replace("http://", "https://", $url, $count);
```

**Note :** Passing 1 directly will throw fatal error (Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference) so you have to pass it last parameter by reference.

Comment: It throws an error because `$count` will just contain the number of replacements performed. It's not a parameter meant to set boundaries or anything.