# Strange behavior of preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to switch the protocol of a link. If it is http, it should become https, and https should become http. I'm using pre_replace but something is going wrong.

Could someone look at my code and tell me what I am missing in my thinking process?

Here is the code:

```
           $pattern = array(
                0 => '/^(http\:)/',
                1 => '/^(https\:)/'
            );
            $replace = array(
                0 => 'https:',
                1 => 'http:'
            );

            ksort($pattern);
            ksort($replace);

            $url = 'http://someurl.com';

            echo $url."<br />";

            $url = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, trim($url),1);

            die($url);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't the first pattern always match, even if the protocol is https?

Comment: Couldn't you just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - replace http with https in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289272/php-replace-http-with-https-in-url)

Comment: @Nanne the duplicate's solution is very wrong. I left a comment there. Code will also create Fatal Error as well.

Comment: But the question is still a dupe, isn't it?

Comment: @Nanne not really, as the 'dupe' question is incorrect and not even valid PHP code. We should not be referring wrong answers even if they may have mistakingly been marked as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You do not need to escape `:`, it is not a special character.
2. You don't need a capture group `()`.
3. You don't need to call `ksort()`, your arrays are already sorted by key when you declare them.
4. You appear to have your code replacing 'http' with 'https' **AND** replacing 'https' with 'http'. Why?

`$url = preg_replace('/^http:/', 'https', trim($url));` will work just fine if you're simply looking to force to https.

### edit

I still don't know why anyone would want to switch both http/https concurrently, but here you go:

```
function protocol_switcheroo($url) {
  if( preg_match('/^http:/', $url) ) {
    return preg_replace('/^http:/', 'https:', $url); // http to https
  } else if( preg_match('/^https:/', $url) ) {
    return preg_replace('/^https:/', 'http:', $url); // https to http
  } else {
    return $url; // for URIs with protocols other than http/https
  }
}
```

You need to separate out the calls to replace so that you do not accidentally chain them like in the original code in the question.

Comment: it wasn't me that downvoted, but I suspect the reason is that the OP explicitly wants to swap http and https -- ie if you have one, then switch to the other. I don't know why you'd do that either, but it's what he wants, and your point 4 doesn't help with that. (points 1-3 are useful bonus but not actually relevant to the meat of the question)

Comment: @VladL I never voted on your answer. Ours both got downvoted right off the bat, and I'm willing to bet by the same guy.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks. That is useful and actually what I did after my code in the question didn't worked. To your 4th point, i thought it would be prevented by the ':' char and the indexes. the ksort() was the rest of my first try ;)

Comment: @ThomasVenturini You don't really need a regex to perform this as it's slower and less efficient than using functions like `strpos()` and `substr_replace()`

Comment: @crypticツ yea but that can't be used in my php-class where I want to have all patterns and replacements as attributes

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working for http -> https (but does work for https -> http) is that preg_replace() first changes the http to https with the first set of key/variable (0), but then immediately back to https -> http, because then the second set of variables (1) in each array is another valid match.

Answer (score 1):

```
//$url = 'http://example.com/https://www';
$url = 'https://example.com/http://www';

$url = (0 === strpos($url, 'http:'))
    ? substr_replace($url, 's:', 4, 1)
    : substr_replace($url, '', 4, 1);

echo $url;
```

This will convert `HTTP -> HTTPS` and `HTTPS -> HTTP`

It does not use a regex which would be slower, and does not use `str_replace()` which can inadvertently replace other portions of the URL. It will only replace the first prefix.

Breakdown : it looks to see if the URL begins with `http:` is it does it will replace the 5th character `:` with `s:` making it HTTPS. Otherwise it will replace the 5th character `s` with nothing making it HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is getting replaced twice. First, first expression matches and `http://someurl.com` becomes `https://someurl.com`. Then, second expression matches and `https://someurl.com` becomes `http://someurl.com`.

It's easier to see with this other example:

```
echo preg_replace(
    array('/fox/',  '/turtle/'),
    array('turtle', 'sparrow'),
 'fox', 1);
```

... that prints `sparrow`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `preg_replace()` does the two replacements one after the other, so that after the first one has run, the second one reverses the effect of the first one.

You need to specify both patterns in a single expression in order to have them run together.

I suggest using `preg_replace_callback()` instead of `preg_replace()`. With this, you can write a more complex output expression, which makes it easier to combine them into a single pattern. Something like this will do the trick:

```
$outputString = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(http|ftp)(s)?(:)/',
    function($matches) {return $matches[1].($matches[2]=='s'?'':'s').':';},
    $inputString
);
```

Hope that helps.

[EDIT] Edited the code so it works for `ftp`/`ftps` as well as `http`/`https`, after comment by OP.

Comment: thanks, the kindliest answer. would like to give you some ups but someone messed up with my reputation so I can't :S
This would work perfect if i just had to check this two protocolls but there will be more.
Thanks very much ^^

Comment: @ThomasVenturini - fixed that for you. Your question wasn't worth -3 anyway; there seems to have been a bit of drive-by downvoting going on here, so hopefully an upvote balances things out a bit. For what it's worth, this answer can be expanded to fit multiple protocols; I'll edit it so it works for `ftp`/`ftps` as well as `http`/`https`, you'll see how easy it is to adapt.